# To prove that two cyclic subgroups H and K within a cyclic group G are the same when their orders are equal

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups

I see in Fraleigh's abstract algebra book, there is a theorem stating that two cyclic subgroups $H$ and $K$ of a cyclic group $G$, denoted as <$a^s$> and <$a^t$>,respectively, are the same, iff their orders are the same. I don't understand why the cyclic subgroup  of $Z_n$ contains all the integers m less than n such that $gcd(m,n)=d$. Or is there any better and brief proof for this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0anO.png)

Comment: [Please do not rely on images](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742), and [please use MathJax to write math](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/742).